# CCAnimation shownig as black rectangle on iPod 4G

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I create an animation like this:

```
//xxx animation cache
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"mainmenu_xxx.plist"];

//xxx blink    
CCAnimation *animXxx1Anim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteSequence:@"char_xxx_loops%@@2x.png" frameSequence:@"02,03,04" delay:1/24.0];    
[animXxx1Anim setRestoreOriginalFrame:NO];
[[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:animXxx1Anim name:@"xxxBlink"];
```

and then run it like this:

```
//blink animation
[animatedXxxSprite runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:[[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] animationByName:@"xxxBlink"]]];
```

It shows as it should on simulator, iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4S, but it shows as a black rectangle on iPod 4G. Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: All devices using same iOS version?

Comment: try using a higher frame delay, ie 0.1 to see if that makes any difference

Comment: @JOM the devices have different iOS versions, but the iPod has the same version as one iPhone 3GS

Comment: Is it ok without using animationCache?

Comment: The thing is I do not really have access to an iPod 4G device.. so I can't test that much, I only know about the problem because my sound designer has one. (and he is like 300Km away)

Comment: The Animation is pretty large though. The images are about 200x200px (400x400px in -hd), may that be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the texture size. It is recomended that the texture size is lower than 1024x1024 pixels.

Also, sometimes, textures are shown with a very small (1-2 px) position error if it is not in POT format.